# Zoom MKMapView to an MKAnnotationView's frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mapkit

I have a grouped pin that I want to zoom in on. Of course I know the coords of the pin, and have it's view rect. I just want to zoom the map to just the right region so that the cluster fully expands showing all pins (*plus a bit of padding*). What's a good way of doing this?

**Sidenote:**
In my setup the cluster pin will automatically be expanded into individual pins when the zoom level increases so I'm good there. What I need to know is how to set the MapView to a new region based on the frame and coords of the cluster pin.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by removing the group pin

```
[mapView removeAnnotation:groupAnnotation];
```

Then add the pins in the cluster

```
[mapView addAnnotations:clusterAnnotations];
```

Then determine the region to zoom to

```
CLLocationDegrees minLat = 90;
CLLocationDegrees maxLat = -90;
CLLocationDegress minLong = 180;
CLLocationDegrees maxLong = -180
[clusterAnnotations enumerateUsingBlock:^(id<MKAnnotation> annotation, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = annotation.coordinate;
    minLat = MIN(minLat, coordinate.latitude);
    maxLat = MAX(maxLat, coordinate.latitude);
    minLong = MIN(minLong, coordinate.longitude);
    maxLong = MAX(maxLong, coordinate.longitude);
}
CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((minLat + maxLat)/2.f, (minLong + maxLong)/2.f);
MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake((maxLat - minLat)*1.25, (maxLong - minLong)*1.25); //1.25 is for padding
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, span);
[mapView setRegion:[mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
mapView.showAnnotations(groupedAnnotations, animated: true)
```

This method will zoom in and position the map automatically so the annotations are all visible.

Answer (score 2):

When user taps the cluster pin you'll have a callback to

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)
```

Now you just need to cast your `MKAnnotationView` to `MKClusterAnnotation`, then you get access to the collection of its member pins:

```
if let clustered = view.annotation as? MKClusterAnnotation {
    clustered.memberAnnotations.forEach { (annotation) in
        // Calculate region boundaries
    }
}
```

Full solution with Nick's calculations:

```
if let clustered = view.annotation as? MKClusterAnnotation {
    var minLat = CLLocationDegrees(exactly: 90)!
    var maxLat = CLLocationDegrees(exactly: -90)!
    var minLong = CLLocationDegrees(exactly: 180)!
    var maxLong = CLLocationDegrees(exactly: -180)!
    clustered.memberAnnotations.forEach { (annotation) in
        let coordinate = annotation.coordinate
        minLat = min(minLat, coordinate.latitude)
        maxLat = max(maxLat, coordinate.latitude)
        minLong = min(minLong, coordinate.longitude)
        maxLong = max(maxLong, coordinate.longitude)
    }

    let centerLat = (minLat + maxLat) / 2
    let centerLong = (minLong + maxLong) / 2
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: centerLat, longitude: centerLong)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: (maxLat - minLat) * 1.5, longitudeDelta: (maxLong - minLong) * 1.5) // with some padding
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: span)

    <your MKMapView>.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Works beautifully, thank you very much 